# eclipse content assistant does not work in one project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have multiple projects in eclipse , eclipse helps me with finding errors and auto completion in all projects except one ! it worked until I did some refactor on the project, and now it doesn't do that any more ! 
It doesn't even help me to access the methods of a class in the same package and it doesn't notify me when I type anything in the code !

what could be the cause ?

Thanks ,
Arian

Comment: Hold on, just polishing up the crystal ball...

Answer (score 1):

Probably, your project doesn't compile anymore. Open the 'Problems' view, to show the possible problems that cause the stop of compilation. Maybe a missing library or dependency.